# Does the changelog of a Kafka Table emit a new event to its stream when the real value of a key remains unchanged after update?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Let's say I have KTable that's keeping track of location data (e.g.: `{'Susan': 'Paris'}`) and have materialized a changelog stream using the `toStream` method of that table.

I know that if were to update the table with a change to key `Susan` (e.g.: `Berlin`) then the changelog stream would emit a new event `{'Susan': 'Berlin'}`. But what if the updated value is the same as the last?--e.g., during an aggregate operation we set `Susan` to `Berlin` a second time.

Does the changelog emit a second `{'Susan': 'Berlin'}` event or are new events only added to the changelog stream when there's a diff between the old and new values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updates are always emitted. There is not check that compares the old and new value, and the assumption is, that the new value is different to the old value and thus emitted every time.

Comment: is there a way to avoid this behavior?

Comment: You can use a stateful `transformer` to "de-duplicate" manually.

Comment: But this requires an extra step and extra state... When creating a KTable from an aggregation, can't I just update my state internally and not output a result somehow?

Comment: That is correct -- it would require a second state. Using the DSL, this is the only way. However, instead of using the DSL, you can use the Processor API and build a custom operator instead of using the DSL to get the behavior your want.